# Updating the data into the database in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have got a problem with updating the data into the database. When I run the code, it will input the data that start with `3061` to `3070` which it should have be `3001` to `3010`, then `3011 to`3020`,`3021`to`3030`until to`3061`to`3070`.

When I try this:

```
for next_day, program_id in zip(nextday_list, program_id_list):
    value = program_id

    for i in range(0,10):
        if value == program_id:
           cur.execute("UPDATE programs SET program_id=? WHERE start_date=?",(value, next_day))
```

It will make the database table to show like this:

```
channel             |   start_date     |  program_id
101 BBC One South E |  20171111230000  |  3061
101 BBC One South E |  20171111233000  |  3062
101 BBC One South E |  20171112000000  |  3063
101 BBC One South E |  20171112013500  |  3064
101 BBC One South E |  20171112014000  |  3065
101 BBC One South E |  20171112060000  |  3066
101 BBC One South E |  20171112090000  |  3067
101 BBC One South E |  20171112102000  |  3068
101 BBC One South E |  20171112123000  |  3069
101 BBC One South E |  20171112133000  |  3070
102 BBC Two         | 20171111232500   |  3061
102 BBC Two         | 20171112010000   |  
102 BBC Two         | 20171112023500   |  
102 BBC Two         | 20171112060500   |  
102 BBC Two         | 20171112065000   |  
102 BBC Two         | 20171112073500   |  
102 BBC Two         | 20171112083500   |  
102 BBC Two         | 20171112093000   |  
102 BBC Two         | 20171112130000   |  
102 BBC Two         | 20171112140000   |
```

It should be:

```
channel             |   start_date     |  program_id
101 BBC One South E |  20171111230000  |  3001
101 BBC One South E |  20171111233000  |  3002
101 BBC One South E |  20171112000000  |  3003
101 BBC One South E |  20171112013500  |  3004
101 BBC One South E |  20171112014000  |  3005
101 BBC One South E |  20171112060000  |  3006
101 BBC One South E |  20171112090000  |  3007
101 BBC One South E |  20171112102000  |  3008
101 BBC One South E |  20171112123000  |  3009
101 BBC One South E |  20171112133000  |  3010
102 BBC Two         | 20171111232500   |  3011
102 BBC Two         | 20171112010000   |  3012
102 BBC Two         | 20171112023500   |  3013
102 BBC Two         | 20171112060500   |  3014
102 BBC Two         | 20171112065000   |  3015
102 BBC Two         | 20171112073500   |  3016
102 BBC Two         | 20171112083500   |  3017
102 BBC Two         | 20171112093000   |  3018
102 BBC Two         | 20171112130000   |  3019
102 BBC Two         | 20171112140000   |  3020
```

Here is the `program_id` data:

```
3001
3002
3003
3004
3005
3006
3007
3008
3009
3010
3011
3012
3013
3014
3015
3016
3017
3018
3019
3020
3021
3022
3023
3024
3025
3026
3027
3028
3029
3030
3031
3032
3033
3034
3035
3036
3037
3038
3039
3040
3041
3042
3043
3044
3045
3046
3047
3048
3049
3050
3051
3052
3053
3054
3055
3056
3057
3058
3059
3060
3061
3062
3063
3064
3065
3066
3067
3068
3069
3070
```

Here is the `program_id_list` list:

```
['3001', '3002', '3003', '3004', '3005', '3006', '3007', '3008', '3009', 
'3010', '3011', '3012', '3013', '3014', '3015', '3016', '3017', '3018', 
'3019', '3020', '3021', '3022', '3023', '3024', '3025', '3026', '3027', 
'3028', '3029', '3030', '3031', '3032', '3033', '3034', '3035', '3036', 
'3037', '3038', '3039', '3040', '3041', '3042', '3043', '3044', '3045', 
'3046', '3047', '3048', '3049', '3050', '3051', '3052', '3053', '3054', 
'3055', '3056', '3057', '3058', '3059', '3060', '3061', '3062', '3063', 
'3064', '3065', '3066', '3067', '3068', '3069', '3070']
```

Here is the `nextday_list` list:

```
['20171111224000', '20171111230000', '20171111233000', '20171112000000', 
'20171112013500', '20171112014000', '20171112060000', '20171112090000', 
'20171112102000', '20171112123000', '20171111224000', '20171111230000', 
'20171111233000', '20171112000000', '20171112013500', '20171112014000', 
'20171112060000', '20171112090000', '20171112102000', '20171112123000', 
'20171111224000', '20171111230000', '20171111233000', '20171112000000',         
'20171112013500', '20171112014000', '20171112060000', '20171112090000', 
'20171112102000', '20171112123000', '20171111224000', '20171111230000', 
'20171111233000', '20171112000000', '20171112013500', '20171112014000', 
'20171112060000', '20171112090000', '20171112102000', '20171112123000', 
'20171111224000', '20171111230000', '20171111233000', '20171112000000', 
'20171112013500', '20171112014000', '20171112060000', '20171112090000', 
'20171112102000', '20171112123000', '20171111224000', '20171111230000', 
'20171111233000', '20171112000000', '20171112013500', '20171112014000', 
'20171112060000', '20171112090000', '20171112102000', '20171112123000', 
'20171111224000', '20171111230000', '20171111233000', '20171112000000', 
'20171112013500', '20171112014000', '20171112060000', '20171112090000', 
'20171112102000', '20171112123000']
```

I have also tried this:

```
for next_day, program_id in zip(nextday_list, program_id_list):
    value = program_id

    if value == program_id:
       cur.execute("UPDATE programs SET program_id=? WHERE start_date=?",(value, next_day))
```

It doesn't make any difference. What I'm expecting to do is I want to find the matching strings of `next_day` from my list to check on the database to see if the strings is matching then I want to input the program ids in 10 rows where the matching `next_day` string are found, then input the 10 other program ids in 10 rows for each channel.

Here is for example: The `next_day` string show `20171111224000` from my list as I want to check them in a database for BBC One, when the matching strings are found I want to input 10 program ids that start from `3001` to `3010` as I want to input them in the same rows where the matching strings are found from my list comparing in the database. Then after this I want to skip to the next channel to find the 10 rows that are matching with `next_day` strings so I want to input the program ids `3011` to 3020` to input them in each row. The same thing it goes for the other channels.

Can you please show me an example how I could input the program ids in 10 rows the same rows as the matching `next_day` strings so I could do the same for other channels?

Comment: any idea??????????????????????

Comment: does anyone know??????????????????]